# Posting App on Behalf of Another Company in Apple App store

Tags: ios, app-store

I have a query regarding uploading of app on Apple app store.

I have an IPA file provided by client & client does not have any Apple iTunes account. Client ask us to upload the app on Apple store on behalf of client's company name.

Can anyone suggest if is it possible to upload the ipa file on behalf of any other company or client? I don't have to show my name on uploaded app.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Apple lately "encourages" companies to publish under their own account, I've seen a couple of rejections similar to this one:

> PLA 1.2
>
> The seller and company names associated with your app do not reflect
>   the brand name in the app or its metadata, as required by section 1.2
>   of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Your app must be published under a seller name and company name that
>   reflects the brand. **If you have developed these apps on behalf of a
>   client, please advise your client to add you to the development team
>   of their Apple Developer account.**
>
> Once created, you cannot change your seller name or company name in
>   iTunes Connect. For assistance with changing your company name or
>   seller name, you will need to contact iTunes Connect through the
>   Contact Us page.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload it to your iTunesAccount on their behalf but the Account name remains the same say `Gaggan` instead of `XYZ Technologies`.

If you want that a/c should be company name (`XYZ Technology`) then you have to purchase an account and supply company docs i.e. Memorandum of Incorporation to Apple. Also they require D-U-N-S Number then the account will be on the company's name. Otherwise if it's not a company a/c then the Account name would be the name as on the credit card that is used for payment

> Apple Developer Program. If you’re an organization interested in creating apps for distribution on the App Store for iPhone, iPad, Mac, and Apple Watch, enroll in the Apple Developer Program. Membership includes access to beta OS releases, advanced app capabilities, and tools needed to develop, test, and distribute apps and Safari extensions for your entire development team. Organizations will sell apps using their legal entity name. Companies and educational institutions must provide a D-U-N-S Number (available for free) registered to their legal entity during the enrollment process.
>   99 USD per membership year

Also read [What You Need to Enroll](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/)'s **Enrolling as an Organization**

Comment: Absolutely. If the client does not have an iTunes account then they will not appear as the publisher on iTunes. They need to get one, and you need to have access

Answer (score 2):

You say you "have an IPA file provided by client"? Do you also have the source code? The app will have to be code-signed, which is usually done in the build process.

Now, maybe a little paranoia, but...

If there is something wrong with the app - malicious code, scam type actions, it suddenly starts popping up porn images, etc... - it will fall on YOU if you submit it under your account. Apple will NOT accept an excuse of "oh, but I was uploading it for a client."

Just something else to consider.

Comment: You can re-sign an IPA in binary form. You should know what exactly you are doing there, and signing it as part of the build process is much easier. However, re-signing binary IPAs is not unheard of, and done by a lot of people

Comment: @below - very true... I was trying to reinforce the idea that *he* would have to code sign it one way or the other, and is taking a risk by signing it with *his* identity if he doesn't have the source code (or, even if he does have the source code, really).